# How can I make a WHERE clause restriction dynamic on ID level

Tags: mysql, sql, count, where-clause

I want to create a WHERE clause where the restriction is dynamic depending on the ID and date I am looking for to do a count on the number of rows on an ID level in one table and bring it into another table:

Table A looks like this with several IDs:

```
ID - Create date
12221 - 12/12/2018
13331 - 12/10/2018
```

Table B has the following information with several IDs

```
ID - Date
12221 - 10/10/2018
12221 - 07/06/2017
13331 - 01/20/2019
```

I now want to do a count of all the rows in Table 2 that have a date in there before the actual signup date per ID. so in the example above it should say:

```
ID - Count
12221 - 2
13331 - 0
```

Not sure how to do that in SQL with a WHERE clause. I could potentially bring in the "create date" as a new column in Table B and do a workaround on that (e.g. 1 if date smaller than create date, and 0 if date bigger than create date) and then put that into the WHERE clause, but since I have a ton of data, that is not the ideal solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select all records from `TableA` and a count of records in `TableB` that have a date that is before the date in `TableA`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TableA (ID INT, CreateDate DATETIME);
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES (12221, '2018-12-12'), (13331, '2018-10-12');

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TableB (ID INT, DDate DATETIME);
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES (12221, '2018-10-10'), (12221, '2017-06-07'), (13331, '2019-01-20');

SELECT  a.ID,
        COUNT(b.ID) AS MatchCount
  FROM  TableA a
    LEFT JOIN TableB b ON b.ID = a.ID AND b.DDate < CreateDate
  GROUP BY ID;

DROP TABLE TableA;
DROP TABLE TableB;
```

Note that in my example I have renamed the `date` column from `TableB` to `DDate`.

Output:

```
ID      MatchCount
12221   2
13331   0
```

In the above SQL, `TableB` is joined to `TableA` using the criteria that the `ID` must be equal and the date must be *before* the created date. The result set is built by counting the number of rows returned from `TableB` that match this criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Join the tables and group with the condition on dates:

```
select b.id, sum(a.createdate is not null) count
from tableb b left join tablea a
on a.id = b.id and b.date < a.createdate
group by b.id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cG3Qohi9JZMnTd9FcCMpbQ/2).
Results:

```
| id    | count |
| ----- | ----- |
| 12221 | 2     |
| 13331 | 0     |
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you every `id` from `TableA` and the desired count:

```
SELECT a.id, COUNT(b.id) AS preSignupEntries
FROM TableA AS a
LEFT JOIN TableB AS b ON a.id = b.id AND a.`Create date` > b.`Date`
GROUP BY a.id;
```

*COUNT, like most aggregate functions, ignores NULL values.*

Edit: this assumes your "date" fields are actually a date data type; if you are storing them as strings, you'll need to do some parsing.

Edit2: Using an INNER JOIN could be slightly faster if you do not actually care about TableA entries without predated TableB entries.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.id, IFNULL((select count(b.id)
from tableb b 
where a.id = b.id and b.date < a.createdate
group by b.id ),0) as total
from tablea a
```

For the scenario the you have a row in table a, but not in table b:

- IFNULL function only applies for mysql.

## table a

```
ID - Create date
12221 - 12/12/2018
13331 - 12/10/2018
13336 - 12/10/2018
```

## table b

```
ID - Date
12221 - 10/10/2018
12221 - 07/06/2017
13331 - 01/20/2019
```

## result

```
ID      MatchCount
12221   2
13331   0
13336   0
```

Answer (score -1):

try
      `Select id,Count(id) From TableB Group By ID`

Comment: Please see the Count on 13331: I only want to count the rows where date is before create date.